# Is it possible to limit the maximum duration of queries in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server

Specifically I'd like to detect when a query has been executing for over 5 minutes and then cause it to rollback, I could no doubt do this at an application level but am investigating if SQL Server has any built in mechanism to do this for me.

Note, for clarification, I'm sadly still running SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the discussion of this question [How do I set a SQL Server script’s timeout from within the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224830/how-do-i-set-a-sql-server-scripts-timeout-from-within-the-script) I have found reference to [There's no such thing as a query timeout...](http://blogs.msdn.com/khen1234/archive/2005/10/20/483015.aspx) article which says what "query timeouts are a client-side concept only".

You could consider using

```
SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT value
```

command, but unfortunately it isn't exactly what are you looking for.

As [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176100.aspx) says it disallows execution of any query
that has an **estimated** elapsed time, in seconds, required to complete the query on a specific hardware configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio, goto Tools > Options > Query Execution.