# Create SQL INSERT Script with values gathered from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a INSERT script in order to insert in another database the same data.
 If in SQL Server I select "Script table as > INSERT To" I can easily recreate the skeleton for the INSERT statement. However since I have several records to migrate, I would prefer to avoid having to insert the values manually.

**Therefore is there any way to "automatically" get the INSERT script with also the values (coming from the target table) filled in?**

I know this could be done with SSIS, but I am wondering whether it would be possible as well with a quicker solution.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can do this with SSMS.

1 - Right-click your database in Object Explorer.
2 - Select *Tasks/Generate Scripts...*
3 - On the *Set Scripting Options* page, click the *Advanced* button and make sure *Types of data to script* is set to *Data only*.

The resulting script will have a `USE DATABASE` statement at the top. Change this to the database you would like to insert the data into.

Comment: FYI you can turn the `USE Database` command off under Tools / Options / SQL Server Object Explorer / Scripting / General scripting options / Script USE <database>

Comment: You'll also need to remove any identity columns manually from the generated T-SQL if you're using the output as a template to insert new records, or set IDENTITY_INSERT on.

Answer (score 6):

Use the **free** [SSMS tools pack to "generate insert statements"?](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9)

Or in SSMS (don't have it on this PC to confirm) the export wizards allows you to "script data" too

Comment: The export wizard allows me to export the data, but not the statement with the data. But +1 for the Tool, looks very good!

Comment: @Luca: the tool is essential! Check RedFilter's answer about the SSMS wizard.

Comment: SSMS is no longer free for 2012+

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the data types, because you need to conditionally enclose string values in quotes or cast numeric values as strings. You also need to deal with problem characters:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable(col1, col2, col3) 
    SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), col1) + ',' 
        + '''' + REPLACE(col2, '''', '''''') + ''','
        + '''' + REPLACE(col3, '''', '''''') + ''';'
    FROM dbo.SourceTable;
```

Vyas has a [pretty complex stored procedure](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt) for this purpose.

Of course you can do this much easier by just saying:

```
INSERT INTO OtherDatabase.dbo.DestinationTable(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.SourceTable;
```

In other words, you don't need to "script" an insert, you can just run it...

Comment: The second approach would be very easy, if only would not be on a completely different intranet/server without a remote access :-(

Comment: @Luca, in that case export a file and bring it in with SSIS or the import Export wizard.

Comment: @HLGEM: the solution provided by RedFilter is the closes to what I was looking for, since it is the most direct. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

use the INSERT INTO ... SELECT format:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/

Answer (score 0):

@RedFilter, your solution is working like a charm for less data **SIZE**.

In my case, When I tried to open the Exported sql file, I faced the OutOfMemoryException.

[image]

**The file size is around 4GB.**

In order to get the data from that file, I tried [BCP(Bulk Copy Program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222442/sql-server-running-large-script-files/57062759#57062759) approach.

Hope that would be help full for someone.