# Copy table from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just created an empty database on my machine. I now wish to copy a table from our server database to this local database.

What sql commands do I need to run to do this? I wish to create the new table, copy data from the old table and insert it into the new table.

Comment: You could create a SQL INSERT script.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515110/create-sql-insert-script-with-values-gathered-from-table

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) to the source server.  The easiest way is to right click "Linked Servers" in  Management Studio; it's under Management -> Server Objects.

Then you can copy the table using a 4-part name, `server.database.schema.table`:

```
select  *
into    DbName.dbo.NewTable
from    LinkedServer.DbName.dbo.OldTable
```

This will both create the new table with the same structure as the original one and copy the data over.

Comment: +1 only answer taking into account that those databases are on **different** servers!

Comment: Will not work if you're working with SQL Server 2000 and 2012+ https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731869/using-sqlncli10-to-create-a-linked-server-to-sql-server-2000-causes-a-fault

Comment: Solution for SQL Server 2000 and 2012+ here (answer with the highest vote, not the marked answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that they are in the same server, try this:

```
SELECT *
INTO SecondDB.TableName
FROM FirstDatabase.TableName
```

This will create a new table and just copy the data from `FirstDatabase.TableName` to `SecondDB.TableName` and won't create foreign keys or indexes.

Answer (score 8):

Another method that can be used to copy tables from the source database to the destination one is the SQL Server Export and Import wizard, which is available in SQL Server Management Studio.

You have the choice to export from the source database or import from the destination one in order to transfer the data.

This method is a quick way to copy tables from the source database to the destination one, if you arrange to copy tables having no concern with the tables’ relationships and orders.

When using this method, the tables’ indexes and keys will not be transferred. If you are interested in copying it, you need to generate scripts for these database objects.

If these are Foreign Keys, connecting these tables together, you need to export the data in the correct order, otherwise the export wizard will fail.

Feel free to read more about this method, as well as about some more methods (including generate scripts, SELECT INTO and third party tools) in this article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 6):

SELECT ... INTO :

```
select * into <destination table> from <source table>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
INSERT INTO ProductPurchaseOrderItems_bkp
      (
       [OrderId],
       [ProductId],
       [Quantity],
       [Price]
      )
SELECT 
       [OrderId],
       [ProductId],
       [Quantity],
       [Price] 
FROM ProductPurchaseOrderItems 
   WHERE OrderId=415
```

Answer (score 5):

If migrating constantly between two databases, then insert into an already existing table structure is a possibility. If so, then:

Use the following syntax:

```
insert into DESTINATION_DB.dbo.destination_table
select *
  from SOURCE_DB.dbo.source_table
[where x ...]
```

If migrating a LOT of tables (or tables with foreign keys constraints) I'd recommend:

- Generating Scripts with the Advanced option / Types of data to script : Data only OR
- Resort using a third party tool.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

To copy the table from one database to another database, first you have to create the exact table structure for the new table as old one, than copy the table entries from one table to another.

Solution for MySQL database

```
create table [new database.]<new table name> like [old database.]<old table name>;
insert [new database.]<new table name> select * from [old database.]<old table name>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want different names for the tables.

If you are using PHPmyadmin you can use their SQL option in the menu. Then you simply copy the SQL-code from the first table and paste it into the new table.

That worked out for me when I was moving from localhost to a webhost.
Hope it works for you!

Comment: For very large tables whose SQL codes would be a pain to copy and paste, PHPmyadmin's **Import** and **Export** menus can easily be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the entire table structure (not just the basic data layout), use **`Task>Script Table As>Create To>New Query Window`** and run in your new database.  Then you can copy the data at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
insert into newdatabase.dbo.table select * from currenttable
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use a tool, like RazorSQL or Toad for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This one line would be sufficient to create as well ass insert the data from the table of other database

create table  as select * from .;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).