how to copy the tables of sql database from one VM to another VM using azure Devops pipeline
I want to copy the specific tables of SQL data base from sorce VM to the destination VM's data base using azure Devops pipeline, can anyone suggest the way to do it

Can you use SQL scripts to copy specific tables from SQL DB in one VM to another without using DevOps? What's your VM? Azure VMs?

its good if you give me powershell script to copy, yeah those are azure VM's

To copy tables from one DB to the DB in another server, you need to add your target server as a linked server of your source server. Then run SQL scripts to copy, for example SELECT * INTO targetTable  FROM [sourceserver].[sourcedatabase].[dbo].[sourceTable]. You can refer to these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603502/copy-table-to-a-different-database-on-a-different-sql-server.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009189/export-table-data-from-one-sql-server-to-another and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285256/copy-table-from-one-database-to-another

Can you check the PowerShell script mentioned in this documnet.

I have copied tables to shared paths in csv format using the below code
$SrcServer = "servername"
$SrcDatabase = "MessageTracker"
$tables = @("MappingType", "Entity", "SystemEntity")
$Schema = "EntityMapping"
foreach ($table in $tables) {
$data = Read-SQLTableData -ServerInstance $SrcServer -DatabaseName $SrcDatabase -SchemaName $Schema -TableName $table
Export data to CSV
$csvPath = "sharedpath$table.csv"
$data | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation
}
write-host Exported table data successfully

how can I update the destination table using the table which is shared in path


its good if you give me powershell script to copy,

You can use below PowerShell script to copy the tables of sql database from one VM to another VM means from one sql server to another sql server:
Param ( 
      [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
      [string] $SrcServer, 
      [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
      [string] $SrcDatabase, 
      [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
      [string] $DestServer, 
      [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]  
      [string] $DestDatabase,
      [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]  
      [string] $LogLocation = "C:\Temp\"
 
  ) 
 

  $ScriptLog = $LogLocation+$SrcDatabase+"_"+$DestDatabase+".log"
 
  Try
  {
    Get-Date >> $ScriptLog
  }
  Catch [System.Exception]
  {
     $ex = $_.Exception 
    Write-Host $ex.Message 
  } 
 
  Try
  {
 
    $TableNames = Read-SQLTableData -ServerInstance $SrcServer -DatabaseName $SrcDatabase -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName "TableList"
 
  }
  Catch [System.Exception]
  {
     $ex = $_.Exception 
    Write-Host $ex.Message 
  } 
 
ForEach($TableName in $TableNames)
{
  Try 
  { 
 
    Write-Host $TableName.TableName
        Copy-DbaDbTableData -SQLInstance $SrcServer -Destination $DestServer -Database $SrcDatabase -DestinationDatabase $DestDatabase -Table $TableName.TableName -DestinationTable $TableName.TableName >> $ScriptLog
 
  } 
  Catch [System.Exception]
  { 
    $ex = $_.Exception 
    Write-Host $ex.Message 
  }
}

For more information you can refer to this document.
