# SQL Server : DELETE statement with rollback INSERT statement into a file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I wonder how you can write a T-SQL `DELETE` statement using `OUTPUT` to spit out `INSERT` statements for those rows that you have deleted (as a rollback plan in the future) instead of just simply outputting the rows that are deleted.

A generic example or code snippet would be up voted.

Include also statement as a whole to export those `INSERT` statements into a file (e.g. using BCP) will be accepted as the answer.

Server is SQL Server 2008R2

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question what you want is to create a file with the insert statements that would undo a delete. If so one way to do this that should work is this:

```
-- set up some test data
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(32))
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (1, 'Fred'),(2, 'Tom'),(3, 'Sally'),(4, 'Alice')

-- drop and create a temporary table to hold the statements to output
IF OBJECT_ID('TempOutputTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempOutputTable 
CREATE TABLE TempOutputTable (SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX))

-- delete a couple of rows from @table1
DELETE FROM @table1
OUTPUT 'INSERT table1 (id, value) VALUES (' + CAST(deleted.id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', ''' + deleted.name + ''')' AS SqlStatement 
INTO TempOutputTable
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2

-- export using bcp
DECLARE @SqlCommand sysname
SELECT @SqlCommand = 'bcp "select * from test.dbo.TempOutputTable" queryout D:\mytest.txt -c -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SqlCommand, NO_OUTPUT

-- remove the temporary table
DROP TABLE TempOutputTable
```

After running this the file `D:\mytest.txt`will contain this:

```
INSERT table1 (id, value) VALUES (2, 'Tom')
INSERT table1 (id, value) VALUES (4, 'Alice')
```

This assumes that `xp_cmdshell` is enabled (to be able to run bcp) and of course you would have to adjust the insert statement according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you can make it without a temp table (i.e. OUPUT INTO @tableVar) and make the INSERT statement generic without knowing the table structure (i.e. in your example, (id, value) and the rest can be auto gen)?

Comment: @user1589188 I think it would be possible to make the statement generic, but I also believe that the temp table is necessary as you need a way to persist the data between the delete session and the bcp session which runs from the outside. I can look into it further later today.

Comment: Yes please, a generic one allows me to use it across many tables without tweaking. Nevertheless, your answer is very clever already.

Comment: @user1589188 I've spent some time looking into this now, and while it certainly can be done in a generic fashion I believe it's a fairly complex process that would take several hours to get working, and I don't really have the time to do it. I think your best option might be to either look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515110/create-sql-insert-script-with-values-gathered-from-table or maybe look into how to use powershell to use the 'generate scripts' function.

Comment: @user1589188 All in all it seems like a lot of work. You might want to consider inserting the deleted records in a backup table instead. That approach would make it very easy to restore deleted information, and it would be a lot easier to create such a solution.