# Open Sql Script with big size

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an SQL script file which it has big size " 1.4 GB " 
when I try to open  it in SQL SERVER Management Studio 
it fails and give me message

> The System can't find the file specified

when I try to open it with notepad++

> file is too big to be opened by notepad++

so does it there anyway to open this script ?

Comment: You want to run it only or open it to see and work on it in SSMS?

Comment: You can open it in WordPad... WordPad can open files of up to dozens of GB. Won't be a pleasure though with that size.

Comment: I want to open it then execute the script

Comment: @Adwaenyth I'm trying to open it with wordpad right now 
i don't know how much time does it need 
I have been waiting about 1 min

Comment: User sqlcmd tool for execute the file [Check these posts.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222442/sql-server-running-large-script-files)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in Command prompt by providing the required details. This command would execute the SQL file without opening the file.

```
sqlcmd -S <ServerName> -U <LoginUser> -P <Password> -d <DatabaseName> -i <Inputfilenamewithpath> -o <Outputfilenamewithpath>
```

Comment: what if I want to change the used database in script 
because when create the script 
the `use XXXDb` command for that DB will be in the first line

Comment: Regenerate your SQL script without using "USE" statement Or else you should edit the Use XXXDb with your desired DBname by opening the SQL script.

Comment: here's the problem that I can't find a tool can open that file to edit it 
otherwise i have to read and edit it programmatically

Comment: You said you cannot open that file then how do you say that file has Use statement....

Comment: because when I create an Sqlscript in management studio 
the use statement will be in the first line

Comment: Regenerate your script by disabling the option "Script USE DATABASE" to False. You can find this option in Advanced button.